# Cassandra: "Pool was closed during initialization" happening in cross-host replication within Cassandra nodes

Tags: cassandra

We are seeing these warning messages "Pool was closed during initialization"

It happens with every cross-host replication within Cassandra nodes. I do not know the impact of it. Can we know why it is happening and is it something to concern about?

```
WARN 19:07:11 Error creating pool to /xx.xx.xx.xx:9042

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ConnectionException: [/xx.xx.xx.xx] Pool was closed during initialization

at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$2.onSuccess(HostConnectionPool.java:149) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]

at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$2.onSuccess(HostConnectionPool.java:135) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]

at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319) [guava-18.0.jar:na]

at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:299) [guava-18.0.jar:na]

at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
```

```
cluster = Cluster.builder()
                    .withMaxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds(20) // default value is 10 seconds
                    .withSpeculativeExecutionPolicy(speculativeExecutionPolicy)
                    .withCredentials("username", "pwd")
                    .addContactPointsWithPorts(cassandraContactPoints)
                    .withoutJMXReporting().build();
this.cluster.init();
session = cluster.connect();
```

Comment: what is your PoolingOptions look like? post the code pertaining to the connection configuration.

Comment: I have added how from the client is getting connecting to the Cassandra Cluster. Are you looking for something specific here?